# Update Table 1 field if criteria is match for a field in Table 2?

Tags: oracle, if-statement, sql-update

I have two tables (see Sample Data):

SAMPLE DATA:

```
APARTMENT TABLE               PAYMENT_STATUS TABLE                
==========================    =======================   
APARTMENT  | DEBT              APARTMENT  |STATUS   
10         |0                  10         |NULL            
22         |500                22         |NULL            
33         |250                33         |NULL
```

I want to update the "PAYMENT_STATUS" table to a number depending on the value of "DEBT" field in the "APARTMENT" table, let's say that the rent price is 500, I want to update "STATUS" field to:

- If the debt is 0, then set the value of "STATUS" to 3
- If the debt is between 1 and 499, then set the value of "STATUS" to 2
- If the debt is 500, then set the value of "STATUS" to 1

I'm quite a rookie with UPDATE statements, anyone can provide help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Merge Into`.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

```
MERGE INTO PAYMENT_STATUS m USING
(SELECT APARTMENT ,
  CASE
    WHEN DEBT = 0
    THEN 3
    WHEN DEBT BETWEEN 1 AND 499
    THEN 2
    WHEN DEBT = 500
    THEN 1
  END status
FROM APARTMENTS
) r ON ( m.APARTMENT = r.APARTMENT )
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE SET m.STATUS = r.STATUS;
```